# Nexmo VoiceXML not working in language other than en-US

Tags: voicexml, vonage

I have a running VoiceXML application that works ok in Nexmo. If I set any language other than en-US the calls want get answered. I just change en xml:lang as in:

```
<vxml application="/dialogue/root/50b9bab0-9ce8-4d7a-9389-09f06aa8f9ee" version="2.1" xml:lang="es-es">
```

I have tried in the vxml above and also in the prompt tag. Any language like es-es, es-ES... even en-UK will make my vxml stop working in Nexmo. 
I am sure script is OK as I can change en-US female and male voice with en-us-male and en-us-female. That works.

Am I missing something?

(I don't think it makes a difference but I use the great Rivr java library to generated vxml)

Comment: This seems to be a technical support question. You should contact: support@nexmo.com.

Answer (score 1):

for me "fr-ca" doesnt work but "fr-ca-female" does work

Comment: Hmmm, this is almost not an answer but it might be an answer if icordoba hadn't tried "fr-ca-female". It would be better as a comment though (for which you'll need 50 rep).